# Why not just using web apps in mobile instead of mobile(android/ios, etc) apps?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, web, cross-platform

Many cross platform solutions has come out for ios/android/tablet,etc, why not just use web instead?  web is the best solution for cross platform and using javascript in HTML5 can achieve plenty of features. So we could develop web-based cross-platform application instead of mobile apps and all you need is a browser (might be different from desktop browsers). However, consider some special features in mobile apps, like sensors, we could implement a javascript framework for mobile apps to achieve mobile features. Any thoughts on that? is it doable?

Answer (score 0):

There are attempts for Mobile Web App Frameworks [Ionic (AngularJS)](http://moduscreate.com/5-best-mobile-web-app-frameworks-ionic-angulalrjs/). Why stick to native apps? Here's a good benchmark [why-mobile-web-apps-are-slow](http://sealedabstract.com/rants/why-mobile-web-apps-are-slow/). The main reason - Javascript is too slow for mobile apps for now to fit every app requirements.